# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string number

Tags: java

the title is covert Bin into Dec, but it goes wrong when input not a binary.

```
public class Bin2Dec {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bin;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter a binary number: ");
        bin = in.next();
        //BinLen = Bin.length();
        char n=bin.charAt(0);
        if(n != 1 && n != 0){
            System.out.println("You did not enter a binary number.");
        }
        int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(Bin, 2);
        System.out.println("Bin= " + bin + " convert to Dec= " + decimalValue);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah? What did you expect `parseInt()` to do when input is not binary?

Comment: Right, so what behaviour did you *expect* it to have? You're currently checking the first character, but that's all - and you're not checking that properly either, as you should be checking against `'1'` and `'0'` rather than 1 and 0. (You're also not abandoning the attempt to convert it after you've detected that it's wrong...)

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code is culprit:

```
if(n != 1 && n != 0) {
    System.out.println("You did not enter a binary number.");
}

int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(Bin, 2);
```

When `if` condition is `false`, i.e. user doesn't enter binary number, the control flow will reach `Integer.parseInt(Bin, 2)` after printing message.

and as per java docs:

> An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the following situations occurs:
>
> The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.
>
> The radix is either smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than Character.MAX_RADIX.
>
> **Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix**, except that the first character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002D') or plus sign '+' ('\u002B') **provided that the string is longer than length 1.**
>
> The value represented by the string is not a value of type int.

Answer (score 1):

You could use  regular expression;

```
 if (! Bin.matches("[01]+")) {
    System.out.println("You did not enter a binary number");
    System.exit(0); 
}else{
   int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(Bin, 2);
   System.out.println("Bin= " + Bin + " convert to Dec= " + decimalValue);
   in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you have a working code:

```
    String Bin;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter a binary number: ");
    Bin = in.next();
    // BinLen = Bin.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < Bin.length(); i++) {
        char n = Bin.charAt(i);
        if (n != '1' && n != '0') {
            System.out.println("You did not enter a binary number.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

        int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(Bin, 2);
        System.out.println("Bin= " + Bin + " convert to Dec= " + decimalValue);
        in.close();
}
```

you are missing the else part of if. and you only check if the first char is 0 or 1 and not the whole string

Comment: You probably should leave `close()` outside the `else`, and drop the extraneous `}`.